# Inequality with conditions $\sum_{cyc}\cos(a\cos(b))\geq \sum_{cyc}\cos(a\cos(c))$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, approximation

it's an inequality by me :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$ and $a\geq b \geq c $ then we have :
>   $$\sum_{cyc}\cos(a\cos(b))\geq \sum_{cyc}\cos(a\cos(c))$$

This inequality is very precise . 
I try Karamata's inequality because the function $f(x)=\cos(x)$ is concave on $[0,1]$ but we have with $a\geq b \geq c$ :
$$a\cos(b)\leq a\cos(c)$$

So we are in the wrong way .

I try also approximation with (for $x\in(0,1)$ ):

$$1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\geq\cos(x)\geq 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$

Remains to show :

$$\sum_{cyc}\Big(1-\frac{(a\cos(c))^2}{2}+\frac{(a\cos(c))^4}{24}\Big)\leq \sum_{cyc}\Big(1-\frac{(a\cos(b))^2}{2}\Big)$$

I think this last inequality is true but now I'm stuck...

I would like a hint if you have.

Thanks a lot for sharing your time and knowledge .

Comment: The last inequality (after Taylor approximation) is wrong. For example, for $a=b=c=\frac13$, we have $$lhs-rhs=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{(a\cos(c))^4}{24}>0$$

Comment: Actually this inequality is [very sharp](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+cos%28a+cos%28b%29%29%2Bcos%28b+cos%28c%29%29%2Bcos%28c+cos%28a%29%29-cos%28a+cos%28c%29%29-cos%28b+cos%28a%29%29-cos%28c+cos%28b%29%29%2C+a+%2Bb%2Bc%3D1%2C0%5Cle+c%5Cle+b%5Cle+a)... We can't loose more than $0.002$ anywhere...

Comment: If $a=b$ or $b=c$, equality occurs.

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch  Very sharp. By using bounds for $\cos x$, it is not hard by computer algebra systems to obtain lower bounds such as $-10^{-5}$.